# How to connect 2-wire door sensor to raspberry pi

Tags: gpio, pi-3, sensor

I recently received this 2-wire door detection sensor (see image below). How can I connect it to my RPi without causing either damage?

After some further research, I would like to edit my question. I discovered that this is an ultra-thin dual magnet opening detector. Its characteristics:
 low voltage output signal, 
 TOR,
 3V3 INPUT,
 output on two wires: DOUT and VCC.

After a search on Google, it seemed to me that the principle of using all sensors of this kind with an RPi is the same. But I have seen fritzing where the two wires are connected directly to the GND and to another GPIO of the RPi. Yet some articles talk about using a resistance ranging between 1-10khm to protect the RPi.

This is the reason why I post this question, I would like to have some help on how to proceed. I am using a Raspberry Pi 3.

[image: image of unknown sensor]

[image: connexion of sensor on breadboard]

Comment: You need to identify the type of sensor.  Once you have done that it should be a simple case of googling the raspberry pi and the sensor name.

Comment: We can't help you with nothing but a picture. What sensor is this? where to find it? (it's documentation) What Pi model do you have?...

Comment: You seem to have it correctly set up. Now, all you need to do is to read GPIO. There is plenty of documentation on this site and elsewhere on the net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From image it's little difficult to check the connections

VCC ---------REED SWITCH WIRE 1

RPI GPIO------REED SWITCH WIRE 2 + RESISTOR FIRST END

GND -----------RESISTOR SECOND END

In this configuation ,when reed switch is open you will get 0V at the RPI GPIO pin and when reed switch is close you will get 5V at RPI GPIO pin

Answer (score 0):

This a reed switch based sensor(2- wire door sensor), it comes normally in two types NC(Normal Close ) or NO (Normal Open) .Majority are NO which closes when other piece i.e magnetic part comes in proximity to it.

Comment: use rc debouncer circuit for interfacing with Rapberry pi  GPIO.   check the below link for circuit diagram                                                  http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/io/input-interfacing-circuits.html

Answer (score 0):

The sensor has a reed switch inside. To use it, connect the one end to ground and the other end to a gpio pin that you could read. In addition connect a resistor with a value of 1K ohm to 10K ohm from the selected gpio pin to +3V3.
While the reed switch is in the open position the gpio pin will read a logical 1.
When the switch is closed, it will read a logical 0. Enjoy your Pi..

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I have very limited knowledge in electronics. To be sure not to be mistaken, are my connections on the photo correct ( I added the photo to the question, see above)? 1 wire to the GND, the second to the gpio 4 with a resistance of 1K ohm between this gpio and the 3v3. And how should the resistance be connected (longer pin and shorter pin) ?